# Exporting profiling information from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way of exporting the javascript profiling information from Chrome?

It would be brilliant if a perftools style report of the javascript code could be generated.

Answer (score 1):

console.profile('mytest')
// do stuff
console.profileEnd('mytest');

console.profiles[0] // obj representing the profiling data.